# Strange code of String

Tags: java, string

help, CodeFight give me this code and say it have 1 line error.
But I can't understand this code.
I thought the line :  `new StringBuilder(inputString).reverse().toString()`
will reverse the String but when I ran it didn't.
code topic: return the right most number of input String.

```
public class Sort {

    static char lastDigitRegExp(String inputString) {
        new StringBuilder(inputString).reverse().toString();
        java.util.regex.Matcher m = java.util.regex.Pattern.compile("[0-9]").matcher(inputString);
        m.find();
        return m.group().charAt(0);
    }


    public static void main(String[] a){
        String m = "ksg23q4yfkpghqap98sr";
        System.out.println(lastDigitRegExp(m));
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know Java but I'm guessing it's not an in-place operation, you need to return the value of the operation into a variable.

Comment: @Rotem is correct - Java String is immutable. You need inputString = new StringBuilder ...

Comment: I suppose codefight is telling you a little more than just that this line has an error? like, for example, what that error might be?

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
 new StringBuilder(inputString).reverse().toString();
        java.util.regex.Matcher m = java.util.regex.Pattern.compile("[0-9]").matcher(inputString);
```

lines of code to :

```
String reverseString = inputString.reverse();
java.util.regex.Matcher m = java.util.regex.Pattern.compile("[0-9]").matcher(reverseString);
```

Should work. The code `new StringBuilder(inputString).reverse().toString();` would work once you store it in a variable, unless then the changes are not made onto the `inputString` as assumed in your existing code.

Note : You shouldn't need `toString()` as you are already dealing with strings.

Comment: Instead of creating one more string (`reverseString`) why you can't do `inputString = inputString.reverse();`

Comment: @Satya sure that can be done, this was just to draw a clear picture of string handling dealt.

Comment: thanks, the code actually is inputString = new StringBuilder(inputString).reverse().toString();

Comment: You don't need the `StringBuilder` in which case.